# Seeking reference - criterion for the existence of a positive linear functional on an ordered vector space below a given function

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, reference-request

The following surely appears somewhere, I would greatly appreciate a reference.  (The aim is to get a measure via Riesz representation, but that has nothing to do with the statement.)

Let $X$ be an ordered vector space over the reals, and let $\varphi\colon X \to {\mathbf R}$.
Then the following are equivalent:

1. There exists a positive linear functional $\lambda\colon X \to {\mathbf R}$ with $\lambda \leq \varphi$.
2. Whenever $\sum x_i \geq 0$, also $\sum \varphi(x_i) \geq 0$.

Comment: Just to clarify - here you mean $\lambda(x)\leq\varphi(x)$ for all $x\in X$ ($\lambda-\varphi$ is monotonic increasing rather than just nonnegative)? Also you only require a reference, not a proof?

Comment: Oops, I mean $\varphi-\lambda$ monotonic increasing!

Comment: I just want $\varphi - \lambda$ to be non negative.  And, no I do not need a proof.